# why InputStream.markSupported always return false [android]

Tags: android

```
/**
 * Indicates whether this stream supports the {@code mark()} and
 * {@code reset()} methods. The default implementation returns 
 * {@code false}.
 *
 * @return always {@code false}.
 * @see #mark(int)
 * @see #reset()
 */
public boolean markSupported() {
    return false;
}


public void mark(int readlimit) {
    /* empty */
}

public synchronized void reset() throws IOException {
    throw new IOException();
}
```

The comments means markSupported() Indicates whether this stream supports the mark() and   reset() methods.

But it always return false.

Link between them is how to produce ?

Thanks

Comment: `InputStream` is an abstract class, meaning it cannot be instantiated directly, and must be subclassed to use. It's up to the concrete subclass implementations to decide if they support marking and resetting. If they do, then they would override the `markSupported()` method to return `true`.

Answer (score 0):

As @Mike explained, the **abstract class** `InputStream` itself does not support `mark`, but the subclasses which `extend InputStream` will `@Override` the methods you posted in your question.

`InputStream`s such as [BufferedInputStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/BufferedInputStream.html) support marking, and overrides `mark()`, `markSupported()` and `reset()` methods.